# Is Lexicographic relation ordered?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Is lexicographic order an ordered relation? if yes, why doesn't it seem to have the reflexive property? based on its definition(read the first $<,$ relates to): $(a,b)<(a',b') $if$ [(a < a')$ OR $((a=a')$ AND $(b < b'))],$ so what if we choose (a,b) and (a,b) to compare? it seems that they don't relate to each other! Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: You are right, its not reflexive.

Comment: So it is not an ordered relation?!

Comment: It seems to me that you can give either an order that satisfies (1) reflexitivity (2) antisymmetry and (3) transitivity or a strict order that satisfies (1) irreflexitivity and (2) transtivity together with a notion of equality that would produce the same effect as the first one by defining $a\leq b$ by $a<b$ or $a=b$. Your strict order together with the notion of equality lexicographic (meaning exactly what it means to mean) give us a total order on the set of words.

Comment: That's exactly the same issue as if someone asks "is the usual relation $<$ on the real numbers an order relation"? The answer is "well, technically no, because it's not reflexive—but of course the closely related $\le$ is an order relation".